# Unable to connect to remote SQL server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using `Visual Studio 2012` s/w and going to create a `SSIS project` with `OLEDB connection` to connect to a `remote SQL server`. My Goal is to transfer data from one table to another table. I create a new connection manager and put the server name and db name. But when I clicked on test connection, every time it failed to connect. I am not sure what need to put in server name and where to put `IP` and `port`. please help me and provide the step by step process

Comment: Please post the error message. That is the first step to troubleshooting

Comment: You're not sure what to put in server name? Who installed the server? How do you know the server exists?

Answer (score 0):

First you should determine the activated protocols (TCP/IP, NetBios) and ports on the remote server with the SQL Configuration Manager / Network Services. If the SQL server is in standard configuration it will be port 1433.

If the remote server is not configured for TCP/IP and you're on a different network subnet with your dev machine, it is possible that you cannot get thru to the server.

You can check that with a ping or tracert. Try

- only the servername
- the FQDN like servername.sub-domain.domain.net

If TCP/IP is working with either the servername or the FQDN you create a SQL client configuration on your machine that corresponds to the name and the remote port you found out in the first step.
You can do that again with SQL Configuration Manager / Client Services or if not available you trick it by starting odbcad32.exe, creating a SQL Server 6 system or user DSN that represents your and progress to the point where you can click "Client configuration". When this is working with SSIS you may delete the DSN again. Only the SQL client configuration entry is important.

Another way is to create a .reg file and add it to the registry directly:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo]
"servername"="DBMSSOCN,servername.domain.net,1433"
```

That's out of the top of my head. Sorry that I cannot be more precise, but I have no actual SQL machine at hand here.